# Flutter Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=Intent

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How do I fix this issue?

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
> ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras)
> }} to activity {packagedName/packagedName.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted

packagedName is my project package name

[image: click here to view full error]

Comment: facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're developing your own plugin for Native Platforms.
The problem is that you can not call "result.success()" or "result.error()" more then once using the same MethodChannel.Result object.

Comment: no, I didn't develop any platform wise plugin. maybe this issue on 3rd party plugin. isn't it?

Comment: Some example code that is giving those errors would be great to see in the original post.

Comment: @Thepeanut what can we do then instead of calling multiple times. EventChannel?

Comment: @AlimovShohrukh as an example - invoke a method from the native part using MethodChannel.invokeMethod() and create a listener using channel.setMethodCallHandler() in dart, or EventChannel if you need an event sink

Comment: @Thepeanut yes, reverse platform channel is the right solution